# How to play online videos in Android?

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am developing a sample media player app in Android to play online videos, I have developed some code to play videos. It plays video from SD card very well, but I am facing two issues in this respect.

1- when I open the app for online videos it shows the video but it does not play the video and after a while it displays an alert dialog having message "Sorry, this video cannot be played".

2-  I have code for "Progress bar", but I don't know where to put the code when the video is downloading from the internet.

Here is my code you can check it. Thanks in advance.

```
myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);


        try
        {

            myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.MY_DOMAIN_NAME.com/videos/video1.mp4"));
            myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            myVideoView.requestFocus();
            myVideoView.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Media found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try like this

```
 VideoView v;
 MediaController mediaController;
 ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

then

```
public void playvideo(String videopath) {
    Log.e("entered", "playvide");
    Log.e("path is", "" + videopath);
    try {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(VideoPlay.this, "",
                "Buffering video...", false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        mediaController = new MediaController(VideoPlay.this);

        Uri video = Uri.parse(videopath);
        v.setMediaController(mediaController);
        v.setVideoURI(video);

        v.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                v.start();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Video Play Error :" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

if still has problem "this video cannot be played" 
try to change video format , hope it will help u.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to play Live video using Video view in Android. i am pasting code here, try this one it will work fine for you.

```
public class PlayVideo extends Activity

{

      //private String videoPath ="Url";

      private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
      String videourl; 
      VideoView videoView ; 

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.play_video);

            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PlayVideo.this, "", "Buffering                 
             video...",true);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true); 


            PlayVideo();

      }
      private void PlayVideo()
      {
            try
            {    
                  getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                  MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(PlayVideo.this);
                  mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);         

                  Uri video = Uri.parse(videourl);           
                  videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                  videoView.setVideoURI(videoPath);
                  videoView.requestFocus();            
                  videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
                  {

                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                        {                 
                              progressDialog.dismiss();   
                              videoView.start();
                        }
                  }); 

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                  progressDialog.dismiss();
                  System.out.println("Video Play Error :"+e.toString());
                  finish();
            } 

      }
}
```

You can find code from below link:

http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.in/search/label/Video-Play%20Live%20Streaming%20in%20Android.

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2020 Kotlin, AndroidX and Android P +

ProgressDialog is deprecated so I used Alert Dialog to show a loading dialog while the file is buffering and then start playback:

```
private fun playVideo(videopath: String) {
    Log.e("Playing Video File: ", "" + videopath);
    try {
        //Show Loader
        val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@ScreenCaptureImageActivity);
        builder.setCancelable(false); // if you want user to wait for some process to finish,
        builder.setView(R.layout.layout_loading_dialog);
        progressDialog = builder.create();

        //add Controller
        val mediaController = MediaController(this@ScreenCaptureImageActivity);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        //Add URI

        //Uncomment to play from local path
        //videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videopath))

        //Example Play from Internet
        videoView.setVideoPath("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4")

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener {
            progressDialog!!.dismiss();
            //Start Playback
            videoView.start()
            Log.e(TAG, "Video Started");
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        progressDialog!!.dismiss();
       Log.e(TAG, "Video Play Error :" + e.localizedMessage);
    }
}
```

**Loader XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Please wait! This may take a moment." />
</LinearLayout>
```

**For Network Access add network config in the manifest, from Android P it's required**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
 <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        >
```

**Add network_security_config.xml in res/xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

[image]