# How to play video using urls instead of assets folder video files in augmentedreality app in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I can able to play videos in Augmented Reality Application using sample app "VideoPlay" here I can able to play different videos for different target images, but here they played videos using assets folder, but I need to play youtube videos instead of assets folder videos.

```
    public class VideoPlayerHelper implements OnPreparedListener,
                                      OnBufferingUpdateListener,
                                      OnCompletionListener,
                                      OnErrorListener
    {
public static final int CURRENT_POSITION            = -1;
private MediaPlayer     mMediaPlayer                = null;
private MEDIA_TYPE      mVideoType                  = MEDIA_TYPE.UNKNOWN;
private SurfaceTexture  mSurfaceTexture             = null;
private int             mCurrentBufferingPercentage = 0;
private String          mMovieName                  = "";
private byte            mTextureID                  = 0;
Intent                  mPlayerHelperActivityIntent = null;
private Activity        mParentActivity             = null;
private MEDIA_STATE     mCurrentState               = MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY;
private boolean         mShouldPlayImmediately      = false;
private int             mSeekPosition               = CURRENT_POSITION;
private ReentrantLock   mMediaPlayerLock            = null;
private ReentrantLock   mSurfaceTextureLock         = null;

// This enum declares the possible states a media can have:
public enum MEDIA_STATE
{
    REACHED_END     (0),
    PAUSED          (1),
    STOPPED         (2),
    PLAYING         (3),
    READY           (4),
    NOT_READY       (5),
    ERROR           (6);

    private int type;
    MEDIA_STATE (int i)
    {
        this.type = i;
    }
    public int getNumericType()
    {
        return type;
    }
}

// This enum declares what type of playback we can do, share with the team:
public enum MEDIA_TYPE
{
    ON_TEXTURE              (0),
    FULLSCREEN              (1),
    ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN   (2),
    UNKNOWN                 (3);

    private int type;
    MEDIA_TYPE (int i)
    {
        this.type = i;
    }
    public int getNumericType()
    {
        return type;
    }
}

/** Initializes the VideoPlayerHelper object. */
public boolean init()
{
    mMediaPlayerLock = new ReentrantLock();
    mSurfaceTextureLock = new ReentrantLock();

    return true;
}

/** Deinitializes the VideoPlayerHelper object. */
public boolean deinit()
{
    unload();

    mSurfaceTextureLock.lock();
        mSurfaceTexture = null;
    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();

    return true;
}

/** Loads a movie from a file in the assets folder */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public boolean load(String filename, MEDIA_TYPE requestedType,
    boolean playOnTextureImmediately, int seekPosition)
{
    // If the client requests that we should be able to play ON_TEXTURE,
    // then we need to create a MediaPlayer:

    boolean canBeOnTexture = false;
    boolean canBeFullscreen = false;

    boolean result = false;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
    mSurfaceTextureLock.lock();

        // If the media has already been loaded then exit.
        // The client must first call unload() before calling load again:
        if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.READY) || (mMediaPlayer != null))
        {
            DebugLog.LOGD("Already loaded");
        }
        else
        {
            if (((requestedType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE) ||                        // If the client requests on texture only
                (requestedType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN)) &&             // or on texture with full screen
                (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH))  // and this is an ICS device
            {
                if (mSurfaceTexture == null)
                {
                    DebugLog.LOGD("Can't load file to ON_TEXTURE because the Surface Texture is not ready");
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                        // This example shows how to load the movie from the assets folder of the app
                        // However, if you would like to load the movie from the sdcard or from a network location
                        // simply comment the three lines below
                     AssetFileDescriptor afd = mParentActivity.getAssets().openFd(filename);                            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                        afd.close();
                        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
                        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(mSurfaceTexture));
                        canBeOnTexture = true;
                        mShouldPlayImmediately = playOnTextureImmediately;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        DebugLog.LOGE("Error while creating the MediaPlayer: " + e.toString());

                        mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.ERROR;
                        mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                        mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    // We need to verify that the file exists
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = mParentActivity.getAssets().openFd(filename);
                    afd.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    DebugLog.LOGD("File does not exist");
                    mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.ERROR;
                    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // If the client requests that we should be able to play FULLSCREEN
            // then we need to create a FullscreenPlaybackActivity
            if ((requestedType == MEDIA_TYPE.FULLSCREEN) || (requestedType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN))
            {
                mPlayerHelperActivityIntent = new Intent(mParentActivity, FullscreenPlayback.class);
                mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                canBeFullscreen = true;
            }

            // We store the parameters for further use
            mMovieName = filename;
            mSeekPosition = seekPosition;

            if (canBeFullscreen && canBeOnTexture)  mVideoType = MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN;
            else if (canBeFullscreen) {             mVideoType = MEDIA_TYPE.FULLSCREEN; mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.READY; } // If it is pure fullscreen then we're ready otherwise we let the MediaPlayer load first
            else if (canBeOnTexture)                mVideoType = MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE;
            else                                    mVideoType = MEDIA_TYPE.UNKNOWN;

            result = true;
        }

    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Unloads the currently loaded movie
    After this is called a new load() has to be invoked */
public boolean unload()
{
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            try
            {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                DebugLog.LOGE("Could not start playback");
            }

            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY;
    mVideoType = MEDIA_TYPE.UNKNOWN;
    return true;
}

/** Indicates whether the movie can be played on a texture */
public boolean isPlayableOnTexture()
{
    if ((mVideoType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE) || (mVideoType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN))
        return true;

    return false;
}

/** Indicates whether the movie can be played fullscreen */
public boolean isPlayableFullscreen()
{
    if ((mVideoType == MEDIA_TYPE.FULLSCREEN) || (mVideoType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN))
        return true;

    return false;
}

/** Return the current status of the movie such as Playing, Paused or Not Ready */
MEDIA_STATE getStatus()
{
    return mCurrentState;
}

/** Returns the width of the video frame */
public int getVideoWidth()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video width if it is not playable on texture");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video width if it is not ready");
        return -1;
    }

    int result=-1;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
            result = mMediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Returns the height of the video frame */
public int getVideoHeight()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video height if it is not playable on texture");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video height if it is not ready");
        return -1;
    }

    int result=-1;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
            result = mMediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Returns the length of the current movie */
public float getLength()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video length if it is not playable on texture");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video length if it is not ready");
        return -1;
    }


    int result=-1;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
            result = mMediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000;
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}


/** Request a movie to be played either full screen or on texture and at a given position */
public boolean play(boolean fullScreen, int seekPosition)
{
    if (fullScreen)
    {
        // If the play request was for fullscreen playback
        // We check first whether this was requested upon load time
        if (!isPlayableFullscreen())
        {
            DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot play this video fullscreen, it was not requested on load");
            return false;
        }

        if (isPlayableOnTexture())
        {
            // If it can also play on texture then we forward information such as whether
            // it is currently playing (shouldPlayImmediately) and in which position
            // it was being played previously (currentSeekPosition)

            mMediaPlayerLock.lock();

                if (mMediaPlayer == null)
                {
                    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                    return false;
                }

                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("shouldPlayImmediately", true);
                else
                    mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("shouldPlayImmediately", false);

                try
                {
                    mMediaPlayer.pause();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                    DebugLog.LOGE("Could not pause playback");
                }


                if (seekPosition != CURRENT_POSITION)
                    mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("currentSeekPosition", seekPosition);
                else
                    mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("currentSeekPosition", mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

            mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
        }
        else
        {
            // If it cannot play on texture then we set these values to default
            mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("currentSeekPosition", 0);
            mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("shouldPlayImmediately", true);

            if (seekPosition != CURRENT_POSITION)
                mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("currentSeekPosition", seekPosition);
            else
                mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("currentSeekPosition", 0);
        }

        // We must pass the current playback orientation of the activity
        // and the name of the movie currently being played
        mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("requestedOrientation", mParentActivity.getRequestedOrientation());
        mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("movieName", mMovieName);
        mParentActivity.startActivityForResult(mPlayerHelperActivityIntent,1);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // If the client requested playback on texture
        // we must first verify that it is possible
        if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
        {
            DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot play this video on texture, it was either not requested on load or is not supported on this plattform");
            return false;
        }

        if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
        {
            DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot play this video if it is not ready");
            return false;
        }

        mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
            // If the client requests a given position
            if (seekPosition != CURRENT_POSITION)
            {
                try
                {
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(seekPosition);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                    DebugLog.LOGE("Could not seek to position");
                }
            }
            else    // If it had reached the end loop it back
            {
                if (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.REACHED_END)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                        DebugLog.LOGE("Could not seek to position");
                    }
                }
            }

            // Then simply start playing
            try
            {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                DebugLog.LOGE("Could not start playback");
            }
            mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.PLAYING;

        mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

        return true;
    }
}

/** Pauses the current movie being played */
public boolean pause()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot pause this video since it is not on texture");
        return false;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot pause this video if it is not ready");
        return false;
    }

    boolean result = false;

    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        {
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                try
                {
                    mMediaPlayer.pause();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                    DebugLog.LOGE("Could not pause playback");
                }
                mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.PAUSED;
                result = true;
            }
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Stops the current movie being played */
public boolean stop()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot stop this video since it is not on texture");
        return false;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot stop this video if it is not ready");
        return false;
    }

    boolean result = false;

    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.STOPPED;
            try
            {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                DebugLog.LOGE("Could not stop playback");
            }

            result = true;
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Tells the VideoPlayerHelper to update the data from the video feed */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public byte updateVideoData()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot update the data of this video since it is not on texture");
        return -1;
    }

    byte result = -1;

    mSurfaceTextureLock.lock();
        if (mSurfaceTexture != null)
        {
            // Only request an update if currently playing
            if (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.PLAYING)
                mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();

            result = mTextureID;
        }
    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Moves the movie to the requested seek position */
public boolean seekTo(int position)
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot seek-to on this video since it is not on texture");
        return false;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot seek-to on this video if it is not ready");
        return false;
    }

    boolean result = false;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        {
            try
            {
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                DebugLog.LOGE("Could not seek to position");
            }
            result = true;
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Gets the current seek position */
public int getCurrentPosition()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the current playback position of this video since it is not on texture");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the current playback position of this video if it is not ready");
        return -1;
    }

    int result = -1;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
            result = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Sets the volume of the movie to the desired value */
public boolean setVolume(float value)
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot set the volume of this video since it is not on texture");
        return false;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot set the volume of this video if it is not ready");
        return false;
    }

    boolean result = false;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mMediaPlayer.setVolume(value, value);
            result = true;
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/**
 *  The following functions are specific to Android
 *  and will likely not be implemented on other platforms
 */

/** Gets the buffering percentage in case the movie is loaded from network */
public int getCurrentBufferingPercentage()
{
    return mCurrentBufferingPercentage;
}

/** Listener call for buffering */
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1) {
    //DebugLog.LOGD("onBufferingUpdate " + arg1);

    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        {
            if (arg0 == mMediaPlayer)
                mCurrentBufferingPercentage = arg1;
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
}

/** With this we can set the parent activity */
public void setActivity(Activity newActivity)
{
    mParentActivity = newActivity;
}

/** To set a value upon completion */
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    // Signal that the video finished playing
    mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.REACHED_END;
}

/** Used to set up the surface texture*/
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public boolean setupSurfaceTexture(int nativeTextureID)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    {
        // We create a surface texture where the video can be played
        // We have to give it a texture id of an already created (in native) // OpenGL texture
        mSurfaceTextureLock.lock();
            mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(nativeTextureID);
            mTextureID = (byte)nativeTextureID;
        mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void getSurfaceTextureTransformMatrix(float []mtx)
{
    mSurfaceTextureLock.lock();
        if (mSurfaceTexture != null)
            mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(mtx);
    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();
}

/** This is called when the movie is ready for playback */
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer)
{
    mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.READY;

    // If requested an immediate play
    if (mShouldPlayImmediately)
        play(false, mSeekPosition);

    mSeekPosition = 0;
}

public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

    if (mp == mMediaPlayer)
    {
        String errorDescription;

        switch (what)
        {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
                errorDescription = "The video is streamed and its container is not valid for progressive playback";
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                errorDescription = "Media server died";
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                errorDescription = "Unspecified media player error";
                break;
            default:
                errorDescription = "Unknown error " + what;
        }

        DebugLog.LOGE("Error while opening the file. Unloading the media player (" + errorDescription + ", " + extra + ")");

        unload();

        mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.ERROR;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
  }
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810159/how-to-play-online-videos-in-android/14810306#14810306

Comment: thankyou.using vediplayer i also played url vedio,but i want this in augumenterd relaity app,see sample app vedio playback i think its diiferent

Answer (score 0):

In VideoPlayback.java Give your Urls like this

```
mMovieName[STONES] = "Url";
mMovieName[CHIPS] = "Url";
```

and In VideoPlayerHelper.java do like this
Comment these for asset folder

```
/*AssetFileDescriptor afd = mParentActivity.getAssets()
                                .openFd(filename);
                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                                afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        afd.close();*/
```

and do this

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
```

Comment: And coment its else part also