# I want put big video on android app

Tags: android

I want put video on my application that I wrote it , the problem the size video is big , so what can I do?! 
I can't upload the video on YouTube because I don't want anyone see the video except who download app.
any way or solution for how could I do that ?!!

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739574/whats-obb-in-android/17739739#17739739

Comment: you can have private video on youtube as far as I remember. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apk file has a size limit of 50 MB. I think you have a couple of options.

1. Put the video on your server and on launch of the app, download the video from the internet and store on the device. Some games work like that by downloading content from private servers or clouds once installed.
2. I am not sure if this can be used, but try creating an expansion file and upload that to the play store and let your app download from there. [Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

Since you don't want non app users to see the video, consider using some DRM so that once the video is downloaded, it is not shared by the users.

Answer (score 0):

Upload video to your server and display it in your application. Play your video using video url. See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810306/1405983).

Answer (score 0):

Use APK Expansions files for external files-
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html